# ListView извлечение данных

Tags: c#, wpf

Застопорился на элементе ListView.
Имеется код:

```
<ScrollViewer                                                    
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
Margin="755,170,10,380">
  <Grid>
    <ListView Name="CoreSystem" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
    SelectedItem="Core1"        
    SelectionChanged="CoreSystemChanged">                                                        
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>                                                            
          <GridView.Columns>                                                                        
            <GridViewColumn Header="Core 1" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Core1}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Core 2" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Core2}"/>
          </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>  
     </ListView.View>
   </ListView>
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Данный ListView связан с БД. Обновление происходит при входе в программу:

```
private void DataBase_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var context = new CoreContainer();
  context.SystemN.Load();
  CoreSystem.ItemsSource = context.SystemN.Local.ToBindingList();
}
```

У ListView есть событие: CoreSystemChanged (см.выше)
Что нужно записать в обработчик чтобы при выделении отображалось Значение Core 1? У других контролов выделение активного значения довольно просто:

```
string comboBox = ComboboxItem.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

с последующим применением MessageBox.Show. но почему то с ListView не работает.

Comment: *но почему то с ListView не работает.* — что происходит при этом?

Comment: Обработчик имеет следующимй вид:              private void CoreSystemChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
 
            var strk = CoreSystem.SelectedItem.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(strk);
        }

Comment: После веделение предполагалось что появится сообщение со значением которое в поле Core 1, но в окошке информация типа System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.НазваниеБД.5JKDFG6SDFKJH90TRYJHC45HJFDHGKJ

Comment: Потому что `SelectedItem` – это весь элемент, который лежит в выделенной строке, ToString вы у него не переопределили, поэтому он просто возвращает название типа

Comment: Если используется принцип ModelFirst, не подскажите где лучше переопределить ToString, в классе SystemN которая используется для построения БД, или в MainWindow? Или тут вообще лучше написать отдельный класс для коллекции?